# Не проходит по тесту задача

Tags: python, олимпиада

Есть такая задача:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

К ней есть разбор:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По нему я написал код. Получилось вот так:

```
n = int(input())
cords = [list(map(int, input().split())) for _ in range(n)]
cords.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
total = None
for col in range(1, n + 1):
    s = 0
    for row in range(1, n + 1):
        cur = cords[row - 1]
        cur_x = cur[1]
        cur_y = cur[0]
        s += abs(cur_x - col)
        s += abs(cur_y - row)
    if total is None:
        total = s
    elif s < total:
        total = s
print(total)
```

Но на 10 тесте он валится. Подскажите что не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В целом вы правильно решили задачу. Есть несколько вещей которые нужно или можно доработать. По убыванию важности:

### Опечатка в коде

Сортировка в вашем коде сделана по номеру столбца, а должна быть сделана по номеру строки.

### Не нужно перебирать столбцы

Хотя в разборе написано обратное, номер нужного столбца можно вычислить не прибегая к перебору. Нужный номер столбца - [медиана](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0_(%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)) номеров столбцов. Чтобы получить медиану координаты сортируются по столбцам и берётся средняя координата. Есть более продвинутые способы находить медиану, но в этой задаче они не дадут выигрыша:

```
n = int(input())
cords = [list(map(int, input().split())) for _ in range(n)]
cords.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
col = cords[len(cords) // 2][1]
cords.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])

s = 0
for row in range(1, n + 1):
    cur = cords[row - 1]
    cur_x = cur[1]
    cur_y = cur[0]
    s += abs(cur_x - col)
    s += abs(cur_y - row)
print(s)
```

### Причесать код

В последнем решении видно что число шагов по горизонтали и по вертикали можно считать независимо. Избавимся от индексов и сделаем код более питоновидным:

```
n = int(input())
rows, cols = zip(*(tuple(map(int, input().split())) for _ in range(n)))

cols = sorted(cols)
col = cols[len(cols) // 2]
sc = sum(abs(c - col) for c in cols)

sr = sum(abs(r1 - r2) for r1, r2 in enumerate(sorted(rows), start=1))

print(sc + sr)
```

Comment: Спасибо. Всё понятно и изложено по полочкам